# Is the usage of "speaks to" new? Is it American?

Tags: american-english

Two examples from Google:

> Doris McCarthy exhibit speaks to the
>   artist as lover of life

and

> A scribble that speaks to wild nature
>   of art

Is this use of 'speaks to' new?  I seem to have only started to hear it about a year ago, and now I hear it everywhere. Is it American?

Comment: The second example seems awful without the 'the'. "A scribble that speaks to the wild nature of art", is wonderful English, for me at least.

Comment: You're missing definite articles in both of those examples, actually.

Comment: Speaks to = addresses ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [post](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1785) on Language Log is interesting. It suggests that, although there's some disagreement about how long it's been used in news publishing, "speak to [some concept]" has been documented since about 400 years ago:

> In the OED's entry for speak, the sub-entry ... II.14.e. Speak to,
> glossed "To treat of or deal with, to discuss or comment on, (a
> subject) in speech or writing", is ... cited from 1610 .... [Mark Liberman]

Personally, I think it feels awkward, as though there *must* be some neater, more established verb we could drop in instead, but *I just can't think of one*.

Comment: The verb *address* can often be used for the sense of 'speak to' when it is being used to mean 'evoke / reflect / represent'.

Answer (score 12):

The [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speak_to) mentions 3 usages:

1/ ([idiomatic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#idiomatic)) To give [evidence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evidence) regarding something; to attest for.

> <sup>2006 Staff of Vault, The College Buzz Book, page 176:</sup>
>
> This definitely speaks to the fact that at Georgetown, beginning at the admissions process, you're not a number but a real person.

2/ ([idiomatic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#idiomatic)) To [address](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/address) a particular topic.

> <sup>1981, McGill journal of education</sup>
>
> Education for being speaks to what grows within the person himself

3/ ([idiomatic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#idiomatic)) To [resonate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resonate) with, to strike a chord in.

> His music really speaks to me.

All three usages don't seem particularly new.

---

> What does 'education for being' mean

The phrase "education for being" refers to an educational philosophy or approach that emphasizes the development of the whole person, focusing on personal growth, self-awareness, and the intrinsic qualities of an individual.
Unlike traditional education models that might concentrate primarily on academic knowledge, technical skills, or vocational training, "education for being" is concerned with fostering inner growth, emotional intelligence, moral values, and the capacity for self-reflection and self-actualization.

In the context of the original question about the novelty and geographical origin of "speaks to," the mention of "education for being" illustrates that the phrase "speaks to" has been effectively employed in English, highlighting that its use is neither particularly new nor confined to American English.

Comment: This is a good answer, antedating the OP's questioned usage to 1981, but your links are all to *Wiktionary*, not Wikipedia.

Comment: @VonC What does "education for being" mean though?

Comment: @StaticBounce I have edited the answer to address your comment/question.

Comment: @VonC Thank you for your effort. I really appreciate it :)